# How do you generate 50 observations of 10 chi^2 (that's \chi square") distributed variables with 50 degrees of freedom?

Tags: r, function, chi-squared

I am trying to generate 50 observations of 10 chi^2 distributed variables with 50
degrees of freedom. Then I have to create a new variable, which is the average of each of these 10 chi^2 distributed variables and create a histogram of this variable (this will be a sample of 10 observations). Any ideas?

Comment: I was given this as a clue:
`chi2histogram <- function(numObs,df,numVar){
mean <- rep(NA, numVar)
for(i in 1:numVar) {
mean[i] <- mean(rchisq(numObs, df, ncp = 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rchisq(10, 50)` will generate 10 random numbers with 50 degrees of freedom from a chi-squared distribution.  We can do 50 replications of that, then take the mean of each. Or we can just create 50 * 10 observations, and split them up into sets of 10.  After that just run `hist` for a histogram.

```
obs <- matrix(rchisq(50 * 10, 50), nrow = 10)
hist(colMeans(obs))
```

[image]

Comment: And if I want to repeat the steps in above for each combination of 10 and 100 chi^2 distributed variables and for each of 50, 100, 1000, 10000 observations, what is the algorithm I have to use?